# How to batch (.bat) create folders with leading zeros, in Windows cmd, from 000 to 999?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The following code create folder names from `0` to `999`:

```
for /l %%w in (0,1,999) do md %%w
```

how do I add the leading zeros in order to create folders from `000` to `999`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```cmd
@For /L %%G In (1000 1 1999)Do @Set "_=%%G"&Call MD "%%_:~-3%%" 2>NUL
```

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```cmd
For /L %G In (1000 1 1999)Do @Set "_=%G"&Call MD "%_:~-3%" 2>NUL
```

Comment: It would be helpful to future readers if you explained how this worked instead of saying "Just do this".

Comment: This works, @KenWhite, by copying and pasting the respective code into the appropriate [tag:batch-file] or [tag:cmd] window and invoking it. The code should "add the leading zeros in order to create folders from 000 to 999".

Comment: I didn't say that it didn't work. I said it should explain **how** that code works, to that the poster and others can learn. Just dumping code that solves the problem isn't sharing any  knowledge.

Comment: The purpose of this site is not to solve immediate problems, but to build a **knowledge base** for programmers. If you don't share any knowledge, but just solve this immediate problem, that isn't what the site is for or how it works. Just dumping code doesn't teach anything to benefit this user in the future except how to ask for copy/paste code here in the future. If the question was *poor, not formatted correct and showed no research*, then you should have voted to close it instead until the poster improves it.

Comment: Speaking of building a knowledge base, I'm surprised that neither one of you bothered to check if this question had already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

"0..999" creates an array of number from zero to 999. The ForEach-Object code uses mkdir to create a directory with the number formatted to three (3) digits.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "0..999 | ForEach-Object {mkdir $('{0:000}' -f $_)}"
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch @lit it works for me.